# gazebo simulation texture or color error. lunar surface is showing yellow black stripes

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-model, sdf, world

[image: screenshot of gazebo simulation]

Hello. I'm trying to make a simulation of moon surface on gazebo. I tried to use this git for importing moon surface model.
https://github.com/MobileRobots/amr-ros-config/tree/master/gazebo/models/apollo15_landing_site_1000x1000
The problem is this. I succeeded to upload moon surface on gazebo, but the problem is the texture or color isn't correct.
I thought it was problem of getting texture image is having a problem so I copied texture file from git link to usr/share/gazebo-11/media/materials/textures folder.
Also I tried to change jpg file to png file, but nothing solves the problem.
How can I change the color or texture of model?
Thanks for reading and wishing I can solve the answer from your helps.
For asking specific question, I'm uploading world code and sdf code

empty.world

```
<include>
  <uri>model://apollo15_landing_site_1000x1000</uri>
</include>
<light name='sun' type='directional'>
  <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
  <pose>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
  <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
  <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
  <attenuation>
    <range>1000</range>
    <constant>0.9</constant>
    <linear>0.01</linear>
    <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
  </attenuation>
  <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
  <spot>
    <inner_angle>0</inner_angle>
    <outer_angle>0</outer_angle>
    <falloff>0</falloff>
  </spot>
</light>
<model name='ground_plane'>
  <static>1</static>
  <link name='link'>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <plane>
          <normal>0 0 1</normal>
          <size>100 100</size>
        </plane>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <contact>
          <collide_bitmask>65535</collide_bitmask>
          <ode/>
        </contact>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>100</mu>
            <mu2>50</mu2>
          </ode>
          <torsional>
            <ode/>
          </torsional>
        </friction>
        <bounce/>
      </surface>
      <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
    </collision>
    <visual name='visual'>
      <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>
      <geometry>
        <plane>
          <normal>0 0 1</normal>
          <size>100 100</size>
        </plane>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <script>
          <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
          <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
        </script>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
    <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
  </link>
</model>
<gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
<magnetic_field>6e-06 2.3e-05 -4.2e-05</magnetic_field>
<atmosphere type='adiabatic'/>
<physics type='ode'>
  <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
  <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
</physics>
<scene>
  <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
  <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
  <shadows>1</shadows>
</scene>
<wind/>
<spherical_coordinates>
  <surface_model>EARTH_WGS84</surface_model>
  <latitude_deg>0</latitude_deg>
  <longitude_deg>0</longitude_deg>
  <elevation>0</elevation>
  <heading_deg>0</heading_deg>
</spherical_coordinates>
<state world_name='default'>
  <sim_time>32 252000000</sim_time>
  <real_time>32 474591156</real_time>
  <wall_time>1696991403 12767677</wall_time>
  <iterations>32252</iterations>
  <model name='ground_plane'>
    <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
    <scale>1 1 1</scale>
    <link name='link'>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <velocity>0 0 0 0 -0 0</velocity>
      <acceleration>0 0 0 0 -0 0</acceleration>
      <wrench>0 0 0 0 -0 0</wrench>
    </link>
  </model>
  <light name='sun'>
    <pose>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
  </light>
</state>
<gui fullscreen='0'>
  <camera name='user_camera'>
    <pose>5 -5 2 0 0.275643 2.35619</pose>
    <view_controller>orbit</view_controller>
    <projection_type>perspective</projection_type>
  </camera>
</gui>
```

Comment: Have a look at `~/.gazebo/server-XXXXX/gzserver.log`, are there any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's from this [path](https://github.com/MobileRobots/amr-ros-config/blob/43715c9a5880d0d2f6354ad7ea5d2f6ac65def40/gazebo/models/apollo15_landing_site_1000x1000/model.sdf#L35)

```
<diffuse>file://media/materials/textures/AS16-110-18026HR-512x512.jpg</diffuse>
```

The `file://` suggests gazebo to look for this `media/materials/textures/AS16-110-18026HR-512x512.jpg` in the `$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` (but putting the texture file in `/usr/share/gazebo-11/media/materials/textures` should also work if you have sourced the `setup.sh` file from gazebo.)

Changing to

```
<diffuse>model://apollo15_landing_site_1000x1000/materials/textures/AS16-110-18026HR-512x512.jpg</diffuse>
```

should work (there is a note about global gazebo path only in that file). Given the file is already 8 years old, I'm not sure what have changed on the heightmap format.

Another place to look for clues when it comes to the graphics is in `~/.gazebo/ogre.log`. There should be some error about texture file not found there.

Comment: so sorry for such a late reply
I've solved
Thank you so much